# Server-side rendering in React and error while using ejs as view engine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router, ejs

So

At first I created my app without any view engine. My server looked like this:

```
var app = express();

const apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target:'http://localhost:3001'
});

app.use('/api', function(req,res){
  apiProxy.web(req,res);
})

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('*', function(req,res){
  //res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
  const clientString = toHtml(req.url);
  res.send(clientString);
});


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});


app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

And my toHtml function looked like this (of course before compiling):

```
function toHtml(location) {
  const routerContext = {};
  const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)(createStore);
  const appString = renderToString(
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
      <StaticRouter location={location} context={routerContext}>
        <Menu />
        <App />
      </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
  );


  return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>html from the server</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bundle.css" />
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="app">${appString}</div>
      </body>

      <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
    </html>
  `;
};


export default toHtml;
```

Everything was working just fine, app was rendering nicely and I was able to route between different components using Links. The problem was that I couldn't reload the page on specified route. For example I could hit refresh on localhost:3000 but after refreshing on localhost:3000/about I was receiving an error "No default engine was specified and no extension was provided. "
So I decided to use ejs as my view engine.

After nessesary chenges my app is looking like this:

```
var app = express();

const apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target:'http://localhost:3001'
});

app.use('/api', function(req,res){
  apiProxy.web(req,res);
})

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  requestHandler(req,res,next);
  }
);


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});


app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

requestHandler:

```
function requestHandler(req, res, next) {
  axios.get('http://localhost:3001/books').then(function(response) {
    const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)(createStore);
    const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers, {
      "books": {
        "books": response.data
      }
    })
    const initialState = JSON.stringify(store.getState()).replace(/<\/script/g, '<\\/script').replace(/<!--/g, '<\\\!--');
    const context = {};

    const reactComponent = renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
          {routes}
        </StaticRouter>
      </Provider>
    );

    if (context.url) {
      redirect(context.status, context.url)
    } else {
      res.status(200).render('index', {reactComponent, initialState})
    }

  })
  .catch(function(err){
        console.log('#Initial Server-side rendering error', err);
      })
};

export default requestHandler;
```

and my index.ejs is very simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>html from the server</TITLE>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0" />

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/darkly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-S7YMK1xjUjSpEnF4P8hPUcgjXYLZKK3fQW1j5ObLSl787II9p8RO9XUGehRmKsxd" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bundle.css" type="text/css"  />
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <DIV id="app"><%-reactComponent-%></DIV>
    <script>window.__INITIAL_STATE__=<%- initialState -%></script>
    <SCRIPT src="./bundle.js"></SCRIPT>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Now I get different error. I can't even load the page and every time I get "Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory..."

I don't even know where should I look for the problem. What is causing the error? Do I really need view engine to perform routing with server-side rendering? How can I do it without it? Please ask for more information if you need some.